# How to use cv::mat in opencl

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencl

#### Problem

I have opencl code which must take `cv::mat` as input and return `cv::mat` as output.

For now I convert the input to regular array of chars and pass it to opencl and convert the output (which is char array) to `cv::mat`.

#### What I have

I try to use `cv::mat` raw data but there are some gaps in the data. For that reason I copy `cv::mat` to the contiguous array, but I'm sure that I can force opencl to use data with gaps .

#### Question

Is it possible for someone to explain how I can avoid copying data to and from the array, and directly use `cv::mat` as input and output?

Comment: it seems you need to learn how to use cv::mat in any library, separately!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42818297/how-to-iterate-every-element-of-cvmat/42818397#42818397

Comment: It seems that cv::mat is just input and output to my code. And iterate all over the elements and copying them to another buffer is obvious temporary solution for me OK???

Comment: What kind of operation are you performing in opencl code? If they are image processing operations then opencv has opencl/cuda implementation of its own.

Answer (score 1):

**Array to Mat**: you can use the "[constructor for matrix headers pointing to user-allocated data](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a)" (see [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/45105/use-allocated-buffer-for-mat-data-pointer/)):

```
Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);
```

**Mat to Ptr**: you can use the [data attribute](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564) (from [this answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/38/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-access-cvmat-elements-in-a-loop/?answer=7420#post-id-7420))

```
unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(img.data);

for(int j = 0;j < img.rows;j++){
    for(int i = 0;i < img.cols;i++){
        unsigned char b = input[img.step * j + img.channels() * i ] ;
        unsigned char g = input[img.step * j + img.channels() * i + 1];
        unsigned char r = input[img.step * j + img.channels() * i + 2];
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to adapt this to your data type.

Comment: Sorry maybe my English is not the best. But this is not what I ask for but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer helps you with your question: [How to launch custom OpenCL kernel in OpenCV (3.0.0) OCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529458/how-to-launch-custom-opencl-kernel-in-opencv-3-0-0-ocl/answer-28644721)

You could maybe use the `UMat` class that OpenCV provides.

```
cv::Mat mat = ...;
// Upload input mat
cv::UMat input_gpu = mat.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
// Create output mat on the GPU
cv::UMat output_gpu(mat_src.size(), CV_32F, cv::ACCESS_WRITE, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);
// Download output mat
cv::Mat output = output_gpu.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
```

From what I understand you should be able to pass the `UMat` directly to your kernel
using `cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadWrite(output_gpu)`. The kernel argument for that mat would then be `__global uchar*`. I'm not sure though, I have only used OpenCV in combination with CUDA so far.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm rather interested how to use opencl instead of cv rapper around opencl. I will give you + and if there is no more useful answer from yours I will accept yours