# OpenCL in OpenCV 3 does not see more than one GPU

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I was trying to call the Nvidia GT 650M GPU on my MacBook Pro, whose index is `1`, with the integrated GPU having index `0`. (as found from running `$ clinfo`)

Just as mentioned in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529458/how-to-launch-custom-opencl-kernel-in-opencv-3-0-0-ocl/answer-28644721):

> In OpenCV 3.0.0 beta [or above], only a single device is detected:
>
> ```
> context.ndevices() // returns 1 instead of 2
> ```

When I run the code in the answer above, OpenCV will always use the first GPU, despite setting `cv::ocl::Device(context.device(1));`

A discussion thread [in the OpenCV forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/58331/opencv-300-and-opencl-benchmark-sobel-edge-detection/) says that this might be due to the compatibility (1.1) of the Nvidia GPU on the platform, but that is not the case for me.

I wrote a simple OpenCL program to create a context on the Nvidia GPU and run the kernel, and it succeeded. So it is not a OpenCL hardware compatibility issue (the Apple support [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823) also confirms this).

What I tried and not seems to be helping:

- Turn off *auto graphics switching* in System Preferences.
- Switch to Nvidia Web Driver (from macOS native driver) and install CUDA.

---

- OpenCL: 1.2, on both GPUs
- OpenCV: 3.4.1, from HomeBrew
- OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
- Xcode: 9.3

Comment: Have you tried settings the 650M as your default system graphics card? Try disable your integrated graphics and see if it uses the 650M at all. I had similar issues on my ASUS laptop running Linux with a 960M. The solution was to use the NVIDIA card as the default and integrated graphics as secondary in the display settings of the OS.

Comment: @sparkplug Do you mean disabling automatic graphics switching in Energy Saver?

Comment: If you have access to the NVIDIA control panel, I think you can set the default card there, if not then it should be in the display settings. I am not very familiar with mac so do not know the specifics of how to set the default card.

Comment: @sparkplug Thanks for the inspection! On Mac, I can ask the OS to use Nvidia GPU, but that does not help with the situation. I added the fact in the question that the Nvidia GPU is available in OpenCL programs, but just not in `cv::ocl::`.